# awk : best practice for loop variable naming

Tags: awk, conventions

The following code results in an infinite loop because  [*awk* doesn't support local variable in `{ … }` scope](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Variable-Scope.html).

```
#! /usr/bin/gawk -f

function myfunction() {
    for (i = 5; i < 8; i++){
        print "in myfunction(), i="i
    }
}

BEGIN {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        myfunction();
        print i;
    }
}
```

There are two ways to deal with this problem :

1. [Declare loop variable `i` as arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Variable-Scope.html), *e.g.* `myfunction(    i)`.

Note [the extra space before `i` is a coding convention to indicate that `i` is a local variable, not an argument](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Variable-Scope.html).

2. [Use naming convention to prevent 'collision'](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Library-Names.html#Library-Names), *e.g.* `_module_begin_loop`, `_module_myfunction_loop`.

I found that the first solution is quite tricky for a loop variable, since `myfunction()` is not necessarily called in a loop. As for the second, it can make a long name which will decrease readability.

Comment: On a side note, sometimes it is possible, and desirable, to break a problem into different phases and do each in a separate `awk` program, piping the intermediate data between them. You might compare this with how a compiler might do a `cpp` lexical pass, then compile to an RTL language, then assembler, then binary, in 4 separate programs hidden behing the command `cc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer when I was preparing this question.  Other answers are welcome.

In relatively big *awk* project, like [translate-shell](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell) the first solution is used :

```
function parseList(returnAST, tokens,
                   leftBrackets,
                   rightBrackets,
                   separators,
                   ####
                   i, j, key, p, stack, token) {
   ...
}
```

parameters after `####` are local.

*awk* allows to call function with fewer parameters, e.g. `parseList(ast, tokens)` or `parseList(ast, tokens, lb, rb, sep)`. Hence, only the signature is complicated.